# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a web in ASP.net where it shows me publications that our organization puts out. Here's some code from the cs file.

```
//2nd - Setup SQL Command
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [IDTip], [Date], CONVERT(nvarchar(100),[Date], 1) AS Released, [Title], [Image], REPLACE(CONVERT (nvarchar(MAX),[Tip]), '</p>\r\n\r\n<p>', '<p></p>') AS ContentConverted, Recognition, FROM tips WHERE IDTip =" + Request.QueryString["IDTip"], new SqlConnection(HealthReachConString));

//3rd - Attempt to open the connection to the DB
    cmd.Connection.Open();

//4th - Go and fetch some data and apply it to our controls
    SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (objReader.Read())
    {
        lblDate.Text = objReader.GetString(2);
        lblTitle.Text = objReader.GetString(4);
        lblTip.Text = Convert.ToString(objReader["ContentConverted"]);
        imgContentPicture.ImageUrl = "~/files/Health_Tips/" + objReader.GetString(5);
        if (objReader.GetString(5) == " " || objReader.GetString(5) == "")
        {
            imgContentPicture.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            imgContentPicture.Visible = true;
        }

    }
    objReader.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Here's the error that I get.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 23:
>       Line 24:         //4th - Go and fetch some data and apply it to our controls
>       Line 25:         SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>       Line 26:         while (objReader.Read())
>       Line 27:         {
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.]
>           System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1791910
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException 
>       exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5347106
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObjec>t stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, 
>       RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +99
>          PressRoom_Detail.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\web\healthreach\htdocs\Tips_Detail.aspx.cs:25
>          System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>          System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>          System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify your issue, the extra comma is indicating to SQL that another parameter is present, however your parameter is your `FROM`.  Once you remove the comma before the `FROM` your syntax should be valid.  Assuming that you have indicated proper syntax for your `CONVERT` and `Alias` functions.

I'd also like to indicate that your query is prone to SQL Injection.  To resolve that portion you should do:

```
SELECT [IDTip], [Date], 
CONVERT(nvarchar(100),[Date], 1) AS Released, [Title], [Image], 
REPLACE(CONVERT (nvarchar(MAX),[Tip]), '</p>\r\n\r\n<p>', '<p></p>') AS [ContentConverted], [Recognition]
FROM [Tips]
WHERE ([IDTip] = @Id);
```

That is what I saw as faults in the query in my review.

Answer (score 2):

Extra junk:

```
SELECT ... Recognition, FROM ...
                      ^---
```